# HttpResponseMessage Headers.Location Seemingly Being Ignored

Tags: http, response, message

I have the following Web Api method, which works fine as far as creating a new product and setting the location. I know this because I check the response header in Google developer tools and see that it is valid. If I cut and paste the location from tools to the browser, the page loads fine. However, it will not load as a result of returing the response from the method.

```
     public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        productsRepository.Create(product);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, product);

        string uri = Url.Link("ProductsIndex", null);

        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri,"/Products/testview");

        return response;
    }
```

The jQuery that calls PostProduct:

```
    $("#createjQButton").click(function () {

    var product = { Name: $("#Name").val(), Category: $("#Category").val(), Price: $("#Price").val() };
    var json = JSON.stringify(product);

    // Send an AJAX request to create a new product
    $("#createjQButton").click(function () {
    var product = { Name: $("#Name").val(), Category: $("#Category").val(), Price:  $("#Price").val() };
    var json = JSON.stringify(product);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/productsapi',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'     
    });

    return false;
});
```

Why is the location being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I added

```
statusCode: {
   201 : function() {
            window.location.replace("/Products/testview");
   }
```

to my jQuery click function and got to the desired page that way. But should not the original way have worked?